# str_replace in a data frame?

Tags: r, stringr, tidy

In my R code I'm trying to insert a line break into a few longer string values of one of the columns in my data set. The code runs, but the output is always identical to the original string with no changes occurring. When I pull the column out as a vector and apply the same code, it works completely fine. I'm still new to R and the process of removing a column to apply a function and then re-attaching it to the original data frame seems rather complicated. Is there a successful way I can do this just within the data frame?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

dog_descriptions2 <-
  dog_descriptions %>% 
  mutate(breed_primary2 = str_replace_all(breed_primary, c("Pit Bull Terrier" = "Pit Bull\nTerrier", "Labrador Retriever" = "Labrador\nRetriever", "Border Collie" = "Border\nCollie")))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be useful to look at your original data frame and the output data frame, because your code works perfectly for me on a dummy data frame:

```r
dog_descriptions <- data.frame(breed_primary = c("Pit Bull Terrier",
                                                 "Labrador Retriever",
                                                 "Border Collie"),
                               number_of_legs = rep(4, 3))
```

So now when I run your code exactly as-is:

```r
dog_descriptions2 <-
  dog_descriptions %>% 
  mutate(breed_primary2 = str_replace_all(breed_primary, c("Pit Bull Terrier" = "Pit Bull\nTerrier", "Labrador Retriever" = "Labrador\nRetriever", "Border Collie" = "Border\nCollie")))
```

and check dog_descriptions2, I get

```r
> dog_descriptions2
>#        breed_primary number_of_legs      breed_primary2
># 1   Pit Bull Terrier              4   Pit Bull\nTerrier
># 2 Labrador Retriever              4 Labrador\nRetriever
># 3      Border Collie              4      Border\nCollie
```

Comment: Thank you! This is correct. I was using View() to inspect my output which doesn't show the "\n" line break. Sigh... Took too long to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would use `str_replace_all` for this task. Instead, I'd recommend using `recode()` or `recode_factor()` in `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# If breed_primary is a character
new.dog.df <- dog_descriptions2 %>%
   mutate(breed_primary2 = recode(breed_primary, 
                                  `Pit Bull Terrier` = "Pit Bull\nTerrier",
                                  `Labrador Retriever` = "Labrador\nRetriever", 
                                  `Border Collie` = "Border\nCollie")

# If breed_primary is a factor
new.dog.df <- dog_descriptions2 %>%
   mutate(breed_primary2 = recode_factor(breed_primary, 
                                  `Pit Bull Terrier` = "Pit Bull\nTerrier",
                                  `Labrador Retriever` = "Labrador\nRetriever", 
                                  `Border Collie` = "Border\nCollie")
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I realized that using View() to inspect my output did not show the "\n" in the string but it did when I used str(). I feel like a dummy but at least the code works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use `case_when()`

```
dog_descriptions %>% 
  mutate(breed_primary2 = case_when(
breed_prmary == "Pit Bull Terrier" ~ "Pit Bull\nTerrier",
breed_prmary == "Labrador Retriever" ~ "Labrador \nRetriever",
breed_primary == "Border Collie" ~ "Border\nCollie",
breed_primary # keep the other cases as they are (?)
)
```

This approach depends on how many cases you actually have and are willing to type out, but it's difficult to say without more information on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! I feel like a dummy. I would always check the output of my code using View() and not another method like just printing the object. The code actually worked correctly, but in View() the string does not show the "\n" for line break. Trials of learning a new programming language, I guess.