# str_replace using arguments from another data frame

Tags: replace, stringr

This is closely related to my question:
[str_replace in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413240/str-replace-in-a-data-frame/75399076#75399076)

So I want to solve this problem:

```
dog_descriptions <- data.frame(breed_primary = c("Pit Bull Terrier",
                                                 "Labrador Retriever",
                                                 "Border Collie"),
                               number_of_legs = rep(4, 3))

dog_descriptions2 <-
  dog_descriptions %>% 
  mutate(breed_primary2 = str_replace_all(breed_primary, c("Pit Bull Terrier" = "Pit Bull\nTerrier", "Labrador Retriever" = "Labrador\nRetriever", "Border Collie" = "Border\nCollie")))
```

But not using a long text string, but rather the data.frame replacement_input:

Is there any possibility in R to use an object (e.g. the data frame named replacement_input) for the replacement of a complex text string.

```
replacement_input <- data.frame(replace = c("Pit Bull Terrier", 
                                            "Labrador Retriever", 
                                            "Border Collie", 
                                            "Fourth Entry"), 
                                replace_with = c("Pit Bull\nTerrier", 
                                                 "Labrador\nRetriever", 
                                                 "Border\nCollie", 
                                                 "Replace 4th"))
```

Conversion to this format should help:

```
    c("Pit Bull Terrier" = "Pit Bull\nTerrier", "Labrador Retriever" = "Labrador\nRetriever", "Border Collie" = "Border\nCollie"))
```

I did not success with combination of paste0 and stringr::str_c to create the "replacment vector"

Maybe it is also the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html):

> The replacement value [is] usually a single string, but it can be a vector the same length as string or pattern.
> In other words, pass the patterns as one vector, and the replacements as another, and it all works.

In practice:

```
dog_descriptions %>%
      mutate(breed_primary = str_replace_all(breed_primary, 
                                             setNames(replacement_input$replace_with, 
                                                      replacement_input$replace)))

# you could also do:
dog_descriptions %>%
      mutate(breed_primary = ifelse(breed_primary %in% replacement_input$replace, 
                                    replacement_input$replace_with, 
                                    breed_primary))
```

Comment: Hi @Mark- Thanks for the help, I made one step further, however.  This works only if replace and replace_with are length of one 1 - If it exceeds the length of 1 (e.g. 4 in this example) I get the following error message: Can't recycle string (size 5000) to match pattern (size 4). Have tried any combination. Same happens in the example if you add one random line to the replacement_input

Comment: I just reran the code, and it still works @jpm. Unsure what you're talking about

Comment: try to run with this replacement_input: replacement_input <- data.frame(replace = c("Pit Bull Terrier",
                                            "Labrador Retriever",
                                            "Border Collie",
                                            "Fourth Entry"),
                                replace_with = c("Pit Bull\nTerrier",
                                                 "Labrador\nRetriever",
                                                 "Border\nCollie",
                                                 "Replace 4th"))

Comment: gives me: ! Can't recycle `string` (size 3) to match `pattern` (size 4).

Comment: no problem - any Idea how to overcome? It appears that he does not check for pattern length?

Comment: thx a lot - worked with the setNames command!